# SharePoint 365 Remove column headers and count/total in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365-groups, hide-elements, web-partmodern-w

I'm working on a SharePoint 365 list and I'm trying to hide the highlighted portions:

[image]

I'd like to hide the "Answer" column header, the "Question" prefix, and the Count/Total inside the ().  As far as writing script for this, I've been instructed to use the Modern Script Editor webpart, which I'm not very familiar with.

[image]

If anyone can help me accomplish these tasks, it would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Chris

Comment: I think you have used grouping here. Do you need grouping in list view?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure.  The customer just wants "The Red Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog" to be the only thing displayed.  Then when clicked, the content expands.  So I need to be able to remove/hide the "Answer", "Question", and number total found in the parentheses.

Comment: I have a question:  in your image, in the title of the list item the word "Question:" appears.  Is that part of the List Item's Title field?

Comment: Yes, AKA Fritz.  It is part of the Title field.